# Multiprocessing with text scraping

Tags: python, multiprocessing, text-mining

I want to scrape `<p>` from pages and since there will be a couple thousands of them I want to use multiprocessing. However, it doesn't work when I try to append the result to some variable

I want to append the result of scraping to the `data = []`

I made a `url_common` for a base website since some pages don't start with HTTP etc.

```
from tqdm import tqdm

import faster_than_requests as requests   #20% faster on average in my case than urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

def scrape(link, data):
    for i in tqdm(link):
        if i[:3] !='htt':
            url_common = 'https://www.common_url.com/'
        else:
             url_common = ''
        try: 
             ht = requests.get2str(url_common + str(i))
        except:
            pass
        parsed = bs.BeautifulSoup(ht,'lxml')
        paragraphs = parsed.find_all('p')
        for p in paragraphs:
            data.append(p.text)
```

Above doesn't work, since `map()` doesn't accept function like above

I tried to use it another way:

```py
def scrape(link):
    for i in tqdm(link):
        if i[:3] !='htt':
            url_common = 'https://www.common_url.com/'
        else:
             url_common = ''
        try: 
             ht = requests.get2str(url_common + str(i))
        except:
            pass
        parsed = bs.BeautifulSoup(ht,'lxml')
        paragraphs = parsed.find_all('p')
        for p in paragraphs:
            print(p.text)

from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(10)

links = ['link', 'other_link', 'another_link']
data = p.map(scrape, links)
```

I get this error while using  above function:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 354, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'scrape' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

I have not figured a way to do it so that it uses `Pool` and at the same time appending the result of scraping to the given variable

**EDIT**

I change a little bit to see where it stops:

```
def scrape(link):
    for i in tqdm(link):
        if i[:3] !='htt':
            url_common = 'https://www.investing.com/'
        else:
            url_common = ''
        try: #tries are always halpful with url as you never know
            ht = requests.get2str(url_common + str(i))
        except:
            pass
        print('works1')
        parsed = bs.BeautifulSoup(ht,'lxml')
        paragraphs = parsed.find_all('p')
        print('works2')
        for p in paragraphs:
            print(p.text)

links = ['link', 'other_link', 'another_link']
scrape(links) 
#WORKS PROPERLY AND PRINTS EVERYTHING 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(scrape, links))
#DOESN'T WORK, NOTHING PRINTS. Error like above
```

Comment: Can you be more concrete on error? Did it dont have all result in list? Check how to share list between process. PD: in your multiprocessing code you dont append to any list

Comment: I use jupyter. What I got was: `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'scrape' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>` and Kernel kept running

Comment: So it fault to launch you custom function?

Comment: Apparently yes. That's why I changed the code to print the result and later save it to a list, and still the same

Comment: I'd like it to work with the first code with appending. Normally the code works fine without multiprocessing, but scraping 2000 links takes around 15min, so I want to make the process faster

Comment: @TomaszSłowik Doesn’t `multiprocessing.map()` already return a list?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile It does, changed the code, yet it still doesn't work. My function has to be buggy or sth

Comment: Can you do some kind of debugging, I would put one print() statement inside the scrape() function to see if it works...

Comment: @t_e_o I added an update - still the same error `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'scrape' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>`

Comment: Can you check your indentation and so on? It seem that the function can not be found properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `map` function incorrectly.

It iterates over each element of the iterable and calls the function on each element.

You can see the map function as doing something like the following:

```py
to_be_mapped = [1, 2, 3]
mapped = []

def mapping(x): # <-- note that the mapping accepts a single value
    return x**2

for item in to_be_mapped:
    res = mapping(item)
    mapped.append(res)
```

So to solve your problem remove the outermost for-loop as iterating is handled by the map function

```
def scrape(link):
  if link[:3] !='htt':
      url_common = 'https://www.common_url.com/'
  else:
        url_common = ''
  try: 
        ht = requests.get2str(url_common + str(link))
  except:
      pass
  parsed = bs.BeautifulSoup(ht,'lxml')
  paragraphs = parsed.find_all('p')
  for p in paragraphs:
      print(p.text)
```